# Configure select2 API to hide toggle

Tags: jquery-select2

How do I hide *select all* on select2?

https://select2.github.io/options.html
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

'showToggleAll' => false, // does not work

Comment: showToggleAll' => false, //not work

Comment: Improved formatting, translated simple comment to English.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to find out why it does not work sense the demo version works ok but if you need to hide it...

```
$(".s2-togall-button, .s2-togall-select").css("display", "none")
```

run after the select2 has loaded seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct use of that option is like next:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(
    Select2::classname(), 
    [
        'data' => $arrayValues,
        'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'prompt'=> 'Select up to 3 values',
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => false,
            'maximumSelectionLength' => 3,
            'allowClear' => false,
            //'tokenSeparators' => [',', ' '],
            'closeOnSelect' => true,
        ],
        'showToggleAll' => false,
    ]
);
```

I hope will be useful